# What does this notation: MyClassName<String> in Java mean?

Tags: java, twitter

Twitter has released a Java client library and included the following example code for using it:

```
// Connect to the filter endpoint, tracking the term "twitterapi"
Hosts host = new BasicHost(Constants.STREAM_HOST);
StreamingEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi"));

// Drop in the oauth credentials for your app, available on dev.twitter.com
Authentication auth = new OAuth1("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", 
                             "token", "tokenSecret");

// Initialize a queue to collect messages from the stream
BlockingQueue<String> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100000);

// Build a client and read messages until the connection closes.
ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder()
    .name("FooBarBaz-StreamingClient")
    .hosts(host)
    .authentication(auth)
    .endpoint(endpoint)
    .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(messages));
Client client = builder.build;
client.connect();

while (!client.isDone()) {
  String message = messages.take();
  // Do something with message
}
```

Release announcement at:  https://dev.twitter.com/blog/the-hosebird-client-streaming-library

What do the angled brackets mean?

Comment: It indicates a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `messages` is an instance of `LinkedBlockingQueue` that works on objects of type `String`. See java's HashMap for another example, and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) for a brief introduction on Generics in java.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It was useful and pointed me in the right direction for more.  Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the superinterfaces of `BlockingQueue<String>` is Collection.
That means it implements the functionality of `java.util.Collection` and it gives you the possibility to use generics and make the collection cast-save!
With the generic:

```
BlockingQueue<String>
```

you only have the possibility to work with String inside of BlockingQueue.
Try adding another value and your IDE will inform you about the mismatch. That is a great benefit because the check is not done during the runtime of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  For everyone, here is the documentation for [java.util.Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).